# ListItem is not Touchable/ Clickable in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, listitem, onitemclick

I have my class MainActivity which extends ListActivity, i set the adapter to list via custom adapter in `onResume()` method.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() 
{
    super.onResume();
    this.setListAdapter(null);
    adapter=new ContactListAdapter(this, R.id.txvNNPersonId, helper.getContacts(sortByname));       
    setListAdapter(adapter); 
}
```

to handle list item click, i use this

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
    { 
        RelativeLayout r=(RelativeLayout)v;
        TextView txvPersonId=(TextView)r.getChildAt(0);
        int iid=Integer.parseInt(txvPersonId.getText().toString());
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,ViewContactActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("id", iid);
        startActivityForResult(intent, VIEW_RECORD);
        //these is not working, these event is not raised, when clicked on listitem click
    }
```

but it does not work when click/touch on item via mouse, it only works when i use it with item selected and implementing `onItemSelectedListener`

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    RelativeLayout r=(RelativeLayout)arg1;
    TextView txvPersonId=(TextView)r.getChildAt(0);
    int id=Integer.parseInt(txvPersonId.getText().toString());
    Intent intent=new Intent(this,ViewContactActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("id", id);
    startActivityForResult(intent, VIEW_RECORD);
}
```

and this only works with the arrow keys on emulator, but on real devices,(usually)they do not have arrow/navigation keys, how to define click for list item?

EDIT:the row_item.xml

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:longClickable="true"
          android:orientation="horizontal">

 <TextView android:id="@+id/txvPersonId"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="40dp"
          android:visibility="invisible" />   -->

<!-- this is name -->
 <TextView android:id="@+id/txvPersonName"
          android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"             
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="40dp"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          android:text="asd"
          android:textSize="15sp"
          android:paddingBottom="5dp" />

 </RelativeLayout>`
```

Comment: Can you post the XML for your row? Just want to rule out that something in your row is stealing the focus/consuming your touch event instead of the row itself.

Comment: ... and if so (i mean if something is "stealing focus" (Clickable elements like Buttons or ImageButtons)) than this question is asked 100 a month

Comment: which xml, do you want, main.xml or row_item.xml

Comment: row_item or just check if you don't have `Button` or `ImageButton` there

Comment: And If you are trying to listen for a click of a row, you would want to implement an `OnItemClickListener` not an `OnItemSelectedListener`. The former is for `ListView`s while the latter is for `Spinner`s, with reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177507/difference-between-onitemclicklistener-and-onitemselectedlistener-of-adapterview.

Comment: Are you trying to write code for touch events and mouse / trackball / keyboard navigation?

Comment: i want to have display detail activity when touched/tapped/clicked(emulator) on list item

Comment: And if you were to remove the OnItemSelectedListener, nothing would happen?

Comment: no currently i have it commented it and removed the interface for it